# Why does Kotlin sortedWith() not just take a function

Tags: function, kotlin

In this sample code `sortedWith` is used with the `compare` function. It appears that to specify the function one needs it to be inside a `Comparator`. This seems like an extra layer. Why does `sortedWith` not just take a function that is passed two `T` objects and returns an `Int`?

```
fun main(){println(get_list())}
fun get_list(): List<Int> {return arrayListOf(1, 5, 2)
  .sortedWith(object:Comparator<Int>{override fun compare(l:Int,r:Int)=r-l})}
```

[sortedWith reference page](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sorted-with.html):
[image: sortedWith reference page]

Comment: Doesn't answer the question, but you can write it as `.sortedWith(Comparator<Int> { l, r -> r - l})`

Answer (score 0):

Being that sortedWith is only supported in the common libraries, I would reason that it is requiring a Comparable to more safely handle differences in how the target platforms handle comparisons of items.

Due to the receivers of both signatures being a sort of list (Not in the Kotlin type sense) you can expect that comparisons could be between different types between two iterations. 
If you do not have a signature of compareTo between receiver type and input type, then it will not know how to safely convert between a Kotlin comparator versus say a Javascript comparison where

`"" == false` is True

`"Hello World" == false` is False

Though it's likely these kinds of specific language rules are taken into consideration in the language design, this is an example for primitives, where if we had runtime defined objects and other complex information, it could quickly break down.

If the Comparable was not used as an intermediary interface the expected comparisons might make sense in Kotlin, but when translated to the target platform might have unexpected consequences.

Long story short, it's a bit of an extra layer, to provide safety.

Comment: 'Being that sortedWith is only supported in the common libraries' -- The selected 'Common' &  '1.3' indicate what I requested the page to display information about.